# Python Pandas. How to extract single column from downloaded yahoo_fin option chain data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

What is the proper way to extract a single column from downloaded option_chain from yahoo_fin? My code for EXXON MOBILE option chains:

```
from yahoo_fin import options
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

df = options.get_options_chain("XOM")
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 
display(df)
```

display_max_columns does not work either.

Anyway I tried doing some numerical and name extractions, but it did not work out at all. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are stored in a `dict` with key-value values of the type of option and the corresponding `pd.DataFrame`. You can get the keys of the `dict` using `keys()`. Keys are `'calls'` or `'puts'`.

```
from yahoo_fin import options
import pandas as pd

data = options.get_options_chain("XOM")

# access dict by key
calls = data['calls']
puts = data['puts']

calls
```

**Output:**

```
    Contract Name   Last Trade Date Strike  Last Price  Bid Ask Change  % Change    Volume  Open Interest   Implied Volatility
0   XOM220429C00045000  2022-04-21 11:13AM EDT  45.0    43.95   0.00    0.0 0.0 -   -   0   0.00%
1   XOM220429C00060000  2022-03-28 10:19AM EDT  60.0    22.45   0.00    0.0 0.0 -   1   0   0.00%
2   XOM220429C00065000  2022-04-13 2:37PM EDT   65.0    21.40   0.00    0.0 0.0 -   4   0   0.00%
3   XOM220429C00070000  2022-04-21 11:05AM EDT  70.0    19.22   0.00    0.0 0.0 -   50  0   0.00%
4   XOM220429C00072000  2022-04-19 2:41PM EDT   72.0    15.91   0.00    0.0 0.0 -   2   0   0.00%
```

To access a single column of the DataFrame use the column name as a key e. g., `'Contract Name'`.

```
calls['Contract Name']
```

**Output:**

```
0     XOM220429C00045000
1     XOM220429C00060000
2     XOM220429C00065000
3     XOM220429C00070000
4     XOM220429C00072000
5     XOM220429C00073000
```